# How to detect a combination of keys pressed in a Mac app?

Tags: objective-c, macos, keyboard

I know that keyboard events in Mac apps can be triggered like so:

```
- (void) keyDown(NSEvent*)event {
    switch ([event keyCode]) {
        case someKeyCode:
            NSLog(@"blah blah blah");

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

But how would I make my app react to a *combination* of key pressed, such as the [Konami Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konami_Code)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will need to build a history list that keeps track of the keys that were pressed over the past however long. and when the list of keys contains a match for your "Code" whether it be the konami code or otherwise. Your match triggers another event and clears the key history.

add the data to an array via strings for control keys

```
static NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
[array addObject:@"[UP]"]; // etc for each key you would have a special key
```

then you can test like this

```
if ([[array componentsJoinedByString:@""] isEqualToString:@"[UP][UP][DOWN][DOWN]"]){
    array = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self commandfound]
}
```

hope that helps

Comment: Maybe use an array, add keys to the array until the array length matches ten. Then clear the array, unless the keys in the array matches the code.

Comment: well what I would do is add a String for each control key such as [UP] then you can [array componentsJoinedByString:@""] and see if it matches your code. Ill update my answer